# javascript calculating mileage rates

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a HR Mileage and Expenses system but am struggling to come up with a way of calculating the rates correctly.

There are 2 rates for car, motorbike, and bicycle. One rate for upto 10,000 miles one rate for over 10,000 miles.
Lets just take car rates as an example. Currently it's 45pence per mile up to 10,000 miles and 25pence per mile there after.

So I have the variables to hold the business mileage and keep it adding but how can I handle the change over of rates?
For example: BusinessMiles = 9990, Mileage Claimed = 100.
So I need to check the business miles are less than 10,000 then the difference between the business miles and the limit. which is 10 miles @ 0.45 and 90 miles @ 0.25.

With Chris's pointers here's my output:

```
//calculate mileage
var businessMilesClaimed = "100";
var currentMilesClaimed = "12110";

if (currentMilesClaimed < 10000)
    {
        var claimedAmount = +businessMilesClaimed + +currentMilesClaimed;

        if (claimedAmount > 10000)
            {
                var claimCalc1 = (claimedAmount - 10000) * 0.25;
                var claimCalc2 = (10000 - currentMilesClaimed) * 0.45;
                var claimResult = +claimCalc1 + +claimCalc2;
            }
        else
            {
            var claimResult = businessMilesClaimed * 0.45;
            }
    }
else
    {
        var claimResult = businessMilesClaimed * 0.25;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like something you could definitely have tackled. As such, here is some pseudocode to help you:

```
milage := 11,192.
// milage is the amount of miles driven..

if(milage is greater than 10000)
     // If they've driven more than ten thousand miles, calculate the difference.
     milage := 10000.
     changeOverMilage := milage - 10000.
else
      // Otherwise, there is no changeOverMilage so set it to 0.
     changeOverMilage = 0.

// Calculate the cost.
cost := (milage * 0.45) + (changeOverMilage * 0.25)
```

Comment: "Give a man a fish, he'll eat for a day.  Teach a man to fish, he'll eat forever."  I was leaning towards "push the man in the water, and see if he catches the fish."  You were instead kind enough to remind him he has a fishing pole, so +1 for that.

Comment: Ha, lovely analogy. I just don't see the value in blindly handing the answer in cases like this, when OP hasn't displayed much effort to try and solve the issue.

Comment: Hi Chris,
I appreciate the pointers without just giving the answer, otherwise I would never learn! I had it in my head that the calculations would be quite difficult, but looking at it with your pointers showed it was simpler. My output is above.